# 1) Extract submatrices, 2) vectorize and then 3) put back

Tags: matlab, matrix

I simplify my problem, let says I have three matrices.

[image]

I want to extract the red-boxed sub-matrices. I define

```
S = [1 4;
     2 5]
```

that are the linear indices of the above matrices. So, `A(S), B(S)` and `C(S)` can extract the entries of the three matrices.

I pack them into vector by `V = [ A(S)(:); B(S)(:); C(S)(:) ]`. Let says after some manipulations, I obtain a new vector

`V_new = [12 9 8 12 21 8 7 5 3 12 11 10]'`

Here comes to my problem:

E.g for matrix A, I want to obtain

`2->12, 5->9, 4->8 and 6->12`

which are the first four entries of my `V_new`.

Since I have around 200 matrices, I have no idea to swap along the 200 matrices and the updated vector, `V_new` at the same time. Is writing a `for-loop` best way to do this purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are `A`, `B` and `C` separate matrices or could you concatenate to work with a single 3D matrix (i.e. do they all have the same dimensions)? In a 3D matrix, this would be quite simple...

Comment: @dan `A`, `B` and `C` are of the same dimension in my problem. Would you please give me a hint how to work with 3D matrices as you mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `A`, `B` and `C` matrices have the same dimensions, rather work with a 3D matrix.

e.g. assuming your example matrices

```
M = cat(3,A,B,C)
```

No to extract those 4 upper left elements:

```
M_subset = M(1:2,1:2,:)
```

And then to reshape them into the vector you had:

```
V = M_subset(:)
```

then manipulate it to get `V_new` and finally put it back in the original:

```
M(1:2,1:2,:) = reshape(V_new,2,2,[])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The last script is amazing =).