# Design a simple matrix to group values from matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

This problem is a succession of my previous problem:

[1) Extract submatrices, 2) vectorize and then 3) put back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31785708/1-extract-submatrices-2-vectorize-and-then-3-put-back/31786626#31786626)

Now, I have two patients, named `Ann` and `Ben`.

[image]

Indeed the matrices `A` and `B` are data for `Ann` and the matrix `C` is data for `Ben`:

[image]

Now, I need to design a matrix `M` such that `y = M*x` where

`y = [a11, a21, a12, a22, b11, b21, b12, b22]'` which is a vector, resulting from concatenation of the top-left sub-matrices, `Ann` and `Ben`;

`x = [2, 5, 4, 6, 7, 9, 6, 2, 9, 3, 4, 2]'` which is a vector, resulting from concatenation of sub-matrices `A`, `B` and `C`.

Here, the `M` is a `8 by 12` matrix that

`a11 = 2 + 7`, `a21 = 5 + 9`, .., `a22 = 6 + 2` and `b11 = 9`, ..`b22 = 2`.

I design the `M` manually by:

```
M=zeros(8,12)
M(1,1)=1; M(1,5)=1; % compute a11
M(2,2)=1; M(2,6)=1; % compute a21
M(3,3)=1; M(3,7)=1; % compute a12
M(4,4)=1; M(4,8)=1; % compute a22
M(5,9)=1; % for setting b11 = 9, C(1,1)
M(6,10)=1; % for setting b21 = 3, C(2,1)
M(7,11)=1; % for setting b12 = 4, C(1,2)
M(8,12)=1 % for setting b22 = 2, C(2,2)
```

Obviously, in general for `M(i,j)`, `i` means the 8 linear-index position of vector `y` and `j` means linear-index position of vector `x`.

However, I largely simplified my original problem that I want to construct this `M` automatically.

Thanks in advance for giving me a hand.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `x = [2, 5, 4, 6, 7, 9, 6, 2, 9, 3, 4, 2]'` (add the "`3`")?

Comment: @dev Yes, I missed the `3` and I editted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have my solution. I have essentially build the matrix M automatically (from the proper indexes) as you suggested.

```
A = [2 4 8;
    5 6 3;
    10 3 6];

B = [7 6 3;
    9 2 9;
    10 2 3];
C = [9 4 7;
    3 2 5;
    10 3 4];

% All matrices in the same array
concat = cat(3, A, B, C);
concat_sub = concat(1:2,1:2,:);
x = concat_sub(:);

n = numel(x)/3; %Number of elements in each subset
M2 = zeros(12,8); %Transpose of the M matrix (it could be implemented directly over M but that was my first approach)

% The indexes you need
idx1 = 1:13:12*n; % Indeces for A
idx2 = 5:13:12*2*n;   % Indices for B and C


M2([idx1 idx2]) = 1;
M = M2';

y = M*x
```

I have taken advantage of the shape that the matrix M shold take:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can index into things and extract what you want without multiplication.  For your example:

```
A = [2 4 8; 5 6 3; 10 3 6];
B = [7 6 3; 9 2 9; 10 2 3];
C = [9 4 7;3 2 5; 10 3 4];
idx = logical([1 1 0;1 1 0; 0 0 0]);
Ai = A(idx);
Bi = B(idx);
Ci = C(idx);
output = [Ai; Bi; Ci];
y = [Ai + Bi; Ci]; % desired y vector
```

This shows each step individually but they can be done in 2 lines.  Define the index and then apply it.

```
idx = logical([1 1 0;1 1 0;0 0 0]);
output = [A(idx); B(idx); C(idx)];
y = [Ai + Bi; Ci]; % desired y vector
```

Also you can use linear indexing with `idx = [1 2 4 5]'`  This will produce the same subvector for each of `A B C`.  Either way works.

```
idx = [1 2 4 5]';
```

or alternatively

```
idx = [1;2;4;5];
output = [A(idx); B(idx); C(idx)];
y = [Ai + Bi; Ci]; % desired y vector
```

Either way works. Check out `doc sub2ind` for some examples of indexing from MathWorks.

Comment: Thanks and you show me how to construct `x`. However, want I need is a matrix `M` such that by multiplying **`M`** with `x`, I can obtain an `y` automatically.

Comment: `M` is just adding 2 values from `A` and `B` or `C` together...simple addition of the sub vectors will do that.  Again no multiplication needed.  The upper 4 values are `Ai + Bi`.  The lower 4 are `Ci` directly.

Comment: Thanks for giving me comments. I understand your words. However,  my problem is simplified such that simple addition and assignment can do the works. For my real application, I need to construct `M` automatically because I have to handle with many patients and matrices involved are no longer 2D.

Comment: @nam Did you check out my solution? I did build the matrix `M`.

Comment: @josoler yes, thank you. I have been trying your solution and adapting to my case.

Comment: Thanks Matt and josoler for giving me a hand. I am able to build my `M` now.